# Changing Microsoft Query in Excel with Python (pywin32) or VBA

Tags: python, vba, excel, pywin32

I need to create reports for the financial year of the individual sales of each customer (around 500) from 1-Apr 2014 to 31-Mar 2015. Last year when I did this I went in to each report from the previous year and simply changed the date in the query so it brought through that financial year. However, our customer base has grown even further and now it looks like I'll spend hours doing this unless I find out a way to change the query in the background.

I can go through each worksheet in the folder containing these reports and open each file for editing:

```
import os, pythoncom
from win32com.client import Dispatch    

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk("location\of\folder"):
    # Open each workbook
    for filename in files:
        xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(path+"\\"+filename)
        ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

        # Method to alter the query here!!!!
        # Would even be open to doing this with VBA and just calling a macro to run
        #    change the query if that's possible?!

        wb.Close()
        xl.Quit()

pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as it's likely to save me hours upon hours of monotonous work.

Many thanks!

I have just tried the following method for trying to change the SQL using VBA.

```
Sub change_date()

Sheets(1).Select

ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).CommandText = Replace(ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).CommandText, "WHERE (Customers.InvoiceDate>={ts '2013-04-01 00:00:00'} And Customers.InvoiceDate<={ts '2014-03-31 00:00:00'})", "WHERE (Customers.InvoiceDate>={ts '2014-04-01 00:00:00'} And Customers.InvoiceDate<={ts '2015-03-31 00:00:00'})")



End Sub
```

But I am getting a Runtime (9) error: Subscript Out of Range.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out for all who are concerned.

```
Sub change_date()

Dim sh As Worksheet, LO As ListObject, QT As QueryTable

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set QT = sh.ListObjects.Item(1).QueryTable

With QT
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Replace(QT.CommandText, "WHERE (Customers.InvoiceDate>={ts '2013-04-01 00:00:00'} And Customers.InvoiceDate<={ts '2014-03-31 00:00:00'})", "WHERE (Customers.InvoiceDate>={ts '2014-04-01 00:00:00'} And Customers.InvoiceDate<={ts '2015-03-31 00:00:00'})")
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```